# Var(AZ)=A Var(Z) A^T?

Tags: variance, linear-model

I am learning linear models, and I do not understand the following:

$\text{Var}(AZ)=A \text{Var}(Z) A^T$ where $A$ is a constant matrix.  I want to know the variance $\widehat{\beta}$ in a linear model: $y=A\beta + \epsilon$, and $\widehat{\beta}=(A^T A)^{-1}A^T y$.

To show $\widehat{\beta}=\sigma^2 (A^T A)^{-1}$, I need to know $\text{Var}(AZ)=A \text{Var}(Z) A^T$.

How do I show that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the properties of variance is 
\begin{equation}
Var(AZ) = A^{2} Var(Z)
\end{equation}
where A is a constant and Z is a random variable.

The matrix equivalent is the version you're working with, i.e.
\begin{equation}
Var(AZ) = A Var(Z) A^{T}
\end{equation}

Two links for you to check out are [Variance#properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties) on Wikipedia and also these course notes from [STA6707](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~tpark/STA6707/notesresources/randomvectors_reduit.pdf) the University of Florida.

Hopefully this clears up the problem for you.

Note: the question has been modified since the time I provided the above answer, so if you actually want a proof to show $\widehat{\beta}=\sigma^2 (A^T A)^{-1}$, please let me know and I will provide you with a proof and an explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but the proof for the hat of beta was clear to me.  Thank you for the answer of the matrix equivalent of the var(AZ), and that was very helpful.